# Generate random matrix with eigenvalues

Tags: matlab, random

I am doing the following to generate random matrices with eigenvalues in a specific range:

```
function mat = randEig(dim, rReal)

    D=diff(rReal).*rand(dim,1)+rReal(1);
    P=rand(dim);
    mat=P*diag(D)/P;

end
```

But I also want to be able to generate random *real* matrices with complex (conjugate) eigenvalues. How would one do that? The similarity transformation trick would return complex matrices.

**EDIT**: Okay I managed to do it by piggybacking on MATLAB's `cdf2rdf` function (which is basically the second function below).

```
function mat = randEig(dim, rangeEig, nComplex)

    if 2*nComplex > dim
         error('Cannot happen');
    end

    if nComplex
        cMat=diff(rangeEig).*rand(dim-2*nComplex,1)+rangeEig(1);
        for k=1:nComplex
            rpart=(diff(rangeEig).*rand(1,1)+rangeEig(1))*ones(2,1);
            ipart=(diff(rangeEig).*rand(1,1)+rangeEig(1))*i;
            ipart=[ipart; -ipart];
            cMat=[cMat; rpart+ipart];
        end
    else
        cMat=diff(rangeEig).*rand(dim,1)+rangeEig(1);
    end

    D=cMat;
    realDform = comp2rdf(diag(D));
    P=rand(dim);
    mat=P*realDform/P;
end


function dd = comp2rdf(d)
    i = find(imag(diag(d))');
    index = i(1:2:length(i));
    if isempty(index)
        dd=d;   
    else   
    if (max(index)==size(d,1)) | any(conj(d(index,index))~=d(index+1,index+1))
      error(message('Complex conjugacy not satisfied'));
    end
    j = sqrt(-1);
    t = eye(length(d));
    twobytwo = [1 1;j -j];
    for i=index
        t(i:i+1,i:i+1) = twobytwo;
    end 
       dd=t*d/t;
    end
end
```

But the code is ugly, mainly the way `rand` is called multiple times is annoying). If someone wants to post an answer that calls `rand` once and manages to do the trick I will surely accept and upvote.

Comment: dim is simply the dimension of the square matrix that the user wants, rangeEig is the range along the real line where the said matrix's eigenvalues lie, and nComplex is the number of complex eigenvalues in its spectrum.

Comment: I managed a single call to `rand` using `circshift` and `upsample` and `downsample`. Thanks!

Comment: Dude just use dim=10, range=[-10, 0], nComplex=3 for e.g.

Comment: Btw are you asking to remove multiple calls to `rand` in this loop: `for k=1:nComplex`? I think I can vectorise that loop

Comment: I want to minimize the calls to `rand` as much as possible. And the reason I left values unspecified is that it should work for example for dim=10, and nComplex=0,1,2,3,4,5....as well as dim=9 and nComplex=0,1,2,3,4. Its not a thing to be hard-coded if thats what you are trying. The complex conjugacy condition for eigenvalue of a real matrix must always be satisfied.

Comment: If you just want to avoid `rand` being called multiple times, you can generate all  random values in one go and then just use indexing to extract the values and put where you  want. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

I made it either a single call or two calls with this:

```
function mat = randEig(dim, rangeEig, nComplex)

if 2*nComplex > dim
    error('Cannot happen');
end

if nComplex
    cMat=diff(rangeEig).*rand(2*nComplex,1)+rangeEig(1);
    cPart=cMat(1:nComplex)*i;
    cMat(1:nComplex)=[];
    cPart=upsample(cPart,2);
    cPart=cPart+circshift(-cPart,1);
    cMat=upsample(cMat,2);
    cMat=cMat+circshift(cMat,1);
    cMat=cMat+cPart;
    cMat=[diff(rangeEig).*rand(dim-2*nComplex,1)+rangeEig(1); cMat];
else
    cMat=diff(rangeEig).*rand(dim,1)+rangeEig(1);
end
D=cMat;
realDform = comp2rdf(diag(D));
P=rand(dim);
mat=P*realDform/P;
end


function dd = comp2rdf(d)
i = find(imag(diag(d))');
index = i(1:2:length(i));
if isempty(index)
    dd=d;
else
    if (max(index)==size(d,1)) | any(conj(d(index,index))~=d(index+1,index+1))
        error(message('Complex conjugacy not satisfied'));
    end
    j = sqrt(-1);
    t = eye(length(d));
    twobytwo = [1 1;j -j];
    for i=index
        t(i:i+1,i:i+1) = twobytwo;
    end
    dd=t*d/t;
end
end
```

If someone can make it a single call or *shorter/more elegant* code they are welcome to post an answer.